# Trying to assign a single value from a query to a variable... what am i doing wrong?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to to set a variable (v_flag_id) to the result of a query. I've been looking online at examples and it seems like my formatting/syntax is correct. What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RUN_AGG
is
declare
    v_Flag_id Number := select flag_id from flag where flag_tx = 'Processed / Calculated';

CURSOR hours IS
  SELECT distinct(HR) as RHR
  , submission_value_id
  from (
  select  
      v.DATA_DATE,
      v.HR,
      sv.submission_value_id
   from value v
   inner join submission_value sv on sv.value_id = v.value_id
   where sv.SUBMISSION_VALUE_ID NOT IN (
      SELECT SUBMISSION_VALUE_ID FROM VALUE_FLAG WHERE VALUE_FLAG.FLAG_ID = v_Flag_id 
   );
BEGIN
OPEN hours;
 LOOP

FETCH hours into l_hr;
EXIT WHEN hours%NOTFOUND;
  AGG_HOURLY_REG_FINAL(l_hr.RHR);
END LOOP;
CLOSE hours;
END RUN_AGG;
```

The error that I am receiving is as follows:

```
Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one 
of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an 
identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    
 exists prior external language
```

Comment: Why do you think you are doing wrong? Any error message appears, some wrong data?

Comment: Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language

Comment: remove `DECLARE` keyword, please study the [syntax  of CREATE PROCEDURE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RUN_AGG IS
 l_rhr       VARCHAR2 (100);
 l_sub_vl_id VARCHAR2 (100);

 CURSOR hours is
  SELECT distinct (HR) as RHR, submission_value_id
    FROM (SELECT v.DATA_DATE, v.HR, sv.submission_value_id
            FROM value_ v
           INNER JOIN submission_value sv
              ON (sv.value_id = v.value_id)
           WHERE sv.SUBMISSION_VALUE_ID NOT IN
                 (SELECT SUBMISSION_VALUE_ID
                    FROM VALUE_FLAG
                   WHERE VALUE_FLAG.FLAG_ID in
                         (SELECT flag_id
                            FROM flag
                           WHERE flag_tx = 'Processed / Calculated')));
BEGIN
 OPEN hours;
 LOOP
    FETCH hours INTO l_rhr, l_sub_vl_id;
  EXIT WHEN hours%NOTFOUND;
  AGG_HOURLY_REG_FINAL(l_rhr);
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE hours;
END RUN_AGG;
```

- remove `declare`
- take `select flag_id into v_Flag_id from flag where flag_tx =
  'Processed / Calculated';` sql in hours cursor's select. So, remove `v_Flag_id` variable.
- return two variables for two columns `l_rhr` and `l_sub_vl_id`.
- I replaced the name of the table `value` with `value_`, since it's a
  reserved keyword for oracle.

Comment: thank you so much! i was fiddling around and looking at examples. i knew there was something i was missing